# I'm trying to do Simon Game. But audio doesn't work on my chrome browser. What to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

The animations work perfectly on shapes. But audio files dont play. What might be the reason?
I added all the html, css, and javascript files for you to see.
It still doesnt let me post it, so i am extending the question. I hope someone can solve this issue. Thank you in advance. I'd be so happy for your help

```js
var buttonColours = ["red","blue","green","yellow"];

var gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*4); // 0-3
    var randomChosenColour = buttonColours[randomNumber];
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColour);

     //1. Use jQuery to select the button with the same id as the randomChosenColour
    $("#"+randomChosenColour).fadeIn().fadeOut().fadeIn();

    var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + randomChosenColour + ".mp3");
    audio.play();

}
nextSequence();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #011F3F;
}

#level-title {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin:  5%;
  color: #FEF2BF;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;

}

.btn {
  margin: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div lass="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you read the console? Check if you are getting any 404 from your audio files, or if something prevents the audio file to be used

Comment: If you look in your browser's console, you'll see this: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. (shortened url removed, long one substituted as per SO posting rules) https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: @AngeLOL yes, it says this Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Comment: tbh i read it but i couldn't get it done @enhzflep  This problem can be solved by that document?

Comment: @Semih - my 2 second take on your code and that document is that you should not be calling `nextSequence();` before the user has interacted with the page. As it stands, your code appears to call that function before the browser has even read the html - i.e immediately after providing the body of that function, you call it. My suggestion is not to call `nextSequence` until the user has clicked something.

Comment: thank you @enhzflep . Well I was trying to do solve it like that, $(...).on("click",nextSequence()); but i dont know what to write in parenthesis, it should be something related to buttons but.. couldnt solve it yet

Comment: @Semih - Well, if you look at a picture of the original Milton Bradley game from 1978 (I own one of these) there's 3 slide switches and 3 buttons in the middle of the console. The red button is only used to start the game. Perhaps this helps - handle clicks on that button to get started, then disable it until the game ends. Here's a close-up: https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/590882/simon-game-facts